# Image loses transparency when using the ImageWorker class

Tags: android

So, I am loading icons from a server using the class found here:

https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/ImageWorker.html

However, the images are not maintaining their transparency. If I view the image in my browser and view the details of the file, it recognizes the file as a PNG file and the transparency is there. It loses it when I load it onto my device.

The issue I believe is that the files do not have a .png extension and Android may not be able to detect that the files are PNG files automatically. This is my best guess, but I'm open to other potential solutions. If it is the lack of extension that is causing the problem, I do not control the server and I cannot get the extension added to the file names. Is there any manipulation I can do in the `ImageWorker` class to add the .png extension before it is sent to the `ImageView` and cached?

EDIT: If I save the file directly to the device and then display the image, it has transparency, even without a .png extension, so my assumption was incorrect. So, the question I have then, is why does it lose transparency when using the `ImageWorker` class?

Comment: You can test if the images themselves are an issue pretty easily by just saving a copy of an image locally and then sticking it into your app (temporarily) as a static resource.

Comment: So, if I save it directly to the device and then display the image, it has transparency, even if the file name does not have a .png extension. So, I guess it is not an extension issue as I had assumed. Anyone have ideas as to why it loses transparency when I use the `ImageWorker` class?

Comment: Why not using a more popular and well-maintained library such as 'Picasso', 'Fresco' or 'Glide'?